# Handle Soap Fault in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have the following setup connected as follows:

1) response & request channel 
2) transformer for ws response/request to a system value object 
3) WS request/response channel 
4) Outbound gateway

```
      <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
  <!-- integration layer -->
  <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
  <int:channel id="getStatusRequestChannel"/>
  <int:channel id="getStatusResponseChannel"/>
  <int:channel id="getStatusWSRequestChannel"/>
  <int:channel id="getStatusWSResponseChannel"/>


  <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
  <!-- gateway definition -->
  <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
  <int:gateway id="mnpGateway" service-interface="com.iquest.play.integration.mnp.MNPGateway">
    <int:method name="getMNPStatus" request-channel="getStatusRequestChannel" reply-channel="getStatusResponseChannel"/>
  </int:gateway>

  <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
  <!-- channel chains -->
  <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
  <int:chain input-channel="getStatusRequestChannel" output-channel="getStatusWSRequestChannel">
    <int:transformer ref="getStatusTransformer" method="transformMNPStatusRequest"/>
  </int:chain>
  <int:chain input-channel="getStatusWSResponseChannel" output-channel="getStatusResponseChannel">
    <int:transformer ref="getStatusTransformer" method="transformMNPStatusResponse"/>
  </int:chain>

  <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
  <!-- outbound gateway -->
  <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
  <int-ws:outbound-gateway id="getStatusOutboundGW"
                           request-channel="getStatusWSRequestChannel"
                           reply-channel="getStatusWSResponseChannel"
                           marshaller="marshaller"
                           unmarshaller="marshaller"
                           destination-provider="mnpUriProvider"/>
```

This is the WSDL :

```
 <wsdl:operation name="getCaseInfo">
  <wsdl:documentation>Message</wsdl:documentation>
  <wsdl:input message="tns:GetCaseInfoRequest">
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output message="tns:GetCaseInfoResponse">
  </wsdl:output>
  <wsdl:fault message="tns:GetCaseInfoError" name="getCaseInfoError">
  </wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
```

How can I catch the Soap Fault?

AFTER EDIT :

I've tried extending a `SoapFaultMessageResolver` and to overide the method 
 `public void resolveFault(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException` 
from there I'm trying to throw a custom IntegrationException (that extends IOException) that I will catch in the method that calls the gateway interface. This is the calling method:

```
    try {
      gateway.MethodA();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      /// I was trying to catch IntegrationException
    }
```

The problem is that the caught exception is of type `WebServiceIOException` that has the root cause `IntegrationException`, and it triggers a huge error log. So I think this approach isn't right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>` is fully based on `WebServiceTemplate` from Spring WS, so there is no any stops to do the same with Soap Fault in Spring Integration.

By default it will be a `WebServiceException`, which is thrown from `WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive` and propagated to the `MessageHandler`, which, in turn, throws it to the caller or send to the `error-channel` as a `Message` `payload`.

As soon as you use `<int:gateway>` that `Exception` might be catched on the method invocation.

If you want to do some logic with that Fault before rethrow you can inject `fault-message-resolver` as an implementation of `FaultMessageResolver` to the `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>`.

Comment: Another related question, if for example the message I receive from the server as a response is not a fault but a custom exception-message. How can I handle that situation? choose behavior based on message type?

Comment: Exactly! Place a `<router>` after `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>` and decide there where to send message further

Comment: Try do not make your `IntegrationException` as an `IOException` just a `RuntimeException`

Comment: Any other options if I want it to be a checked exception?

Comment: It should any one but nor `IOException`, neither `TransportException`, because `WebServiceTemplate` wraps them. But from here you can't do that, because `resolveFault` method signature allows only `IOException` as checked

Comment: Yes, that was the initial cause to extend IOException

Comment: So I've tried using RuntimeException instead of IOException.. and I get the same huge stacktrace...I tracked down where it gets log.. and it is in `doSendAndReceive method` in the `MessagingGatewaySupport` with a logger.warn()

Comment: You can disable that `MessagingGatewaySupport logger.warn()` and just rely on your `try ... catch`. Actually it is already a different question and I don't see how it relates to the original question 'How to handle ...'

Answer (score 1):

We can handle soap fault message during unmarshel and throw the appropriate message to error handler.

This article explains clearly how to handle soap fault message. Hope this might be helpful

http://blog.hostmasterzone.com/how-to-unmarshal-soap-fault-in-spring-integration-web-service/

```
 <bean id="hmzJaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
         <property name="contextPaths">
                <list>
                    <value>org.hmz.request.types</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
<bean id="custJaxbUnMarshaller" class="com.jay.hmz.util.CustJaxbUnMarshaller" >
     <property name="contextPaths">
            <list>
                <value>org.hmz.request.types</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <int:chain input-channel="channel.in" output-channel="channel.out"> 
         <int:transformer method="transformParentRequestById"><bean class="org.jay.hmz.api.transformers.OrderTransformer"/></int:transformer>
         <int-ws:header-enricher><int-ws:soap-action value="${order.request.uri}"/></int-ws:header-enricher> <int-ws:outbound-gateway interceptors="hmzSecurityInterceptor" mapped-request-headers="GUID, USER_REF" request-callback="hmzWebServiceMessageCallback" unmarshaller="custJaxbUnMarshaller" marshaller="hmzJaxbMarshaller" uri="${order.request.uri}"/> 
         <int:transformer method="transformRetrieveParentOrderResponse"><bean class="org.jay.hmz.api.transformers.OrderTransformer"/></int:transformer> 
     </int:chain>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="requestErrorChannel" output-channel="response.out" ref="requestErrorHandler" method="handleFailedOrderRequest"/>

    <bean id="requestErrorHandler" class="org.jay.hmz.api.errorhandler.RequestErrorHandler"/>

public class CustJaxbUnMarshaller extends Jaxb2Marshaller {

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(Source source, MimeContainer mimeContainer)
            throws XmlMappingException {
        LOGGER.debug("Inside Custom JaxbWrapper unmarshal");
        Object mimeMessage = new DirectFieldAccessor(mimeContainer)
                .getPropertyValue("mimeMessage");
        Object unmarshalObject = null;
        if (mimeMessage instanceof SaajSoapMessage) {
            SaajSoapMessage soapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) mimeMessage;
            String faultReason = soapMessage.getFaultReason();
            if (faultReason != null) {
                throw convertJaxbException(new JAXBException(faultReason));
            } else {
                unmarshalObject = super.unmarshal(source, mimeContainer);
            }
        }
        return unmarshalObject;
    }
}
```